# How to integrate ceritifacte with nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, signing

I used letsencrypt to create sertificate for my website and I got following keys generated by certbot

```
cert.pem  
chain.pem  
fullchain.pem  
privkey.pem
```

Following is my nginx conf file. I created public and private key sometime ago which are in followig file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name ec2-54-244-132-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
        location /coupons {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        location /bot {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
        location /v1/coupons/images {
            alias /home/ubuntu/coupon-engine/resources/public/storage/img/;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this configuration. It's work for me.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name ec2-54-244-132-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
        location /coupons {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        location /bot {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
        location /v1/coupons/images {
            alias /home/ubuntu/coupon-engine/resources/public/storage/img/;
        }
}
```

I wrote some documentation for my self, you can see in my blog http://docs.harapan.me/2016/07/konfigurasi-secure-https-pada-web.html , but I am soory that the language in Indonesia